# What are the wells of salvation?

Tags: 1-corinthians, isaiah

Isaiah 12:3

> With joy you will draw water from the wells of salvation.

1 Corinthians 10:4

> and drank the same spiritual drink; for they drank from the spiritual rock that accompanied them, and that rock was Christ.

What are the wells of salvation? Does it allude to Christ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it allude to Christ?

Indeed, it does.

John 4:10

> Jesus answered, "If you knew the gift of God and who is asking you for a drink, you would have asked Him, and He would have given you living water."

John 7:

> 37On the last and greatest day of the festival, Jesus stood and said in a loud voice, “Let anyone who is thirsty come to me and drink. 38Whoever believes in me, as Scripture has said, rivers of **living water** will flow from within them.” 39By this he meant the **Spirit**, whom those who believed in him were later to receive. Up to that time the Spirit had not been given, since Jesus had not yet been glorified.

1 Corinthians 3:16

> Do you not know that you are God’s temple and that God’s Spirit dwells in you?

What are the wells of salvation?

Ultimately, they point to the Holy Spirit who dwells in believers. The Spirit is a deposit guaranteeing our salvation.

Isaiah often prophecied about Jesus.

Isaiah 12:

> 3 With joy you will draw water
> from the wells of **salvation**.
> 4In that day you will say:
> “Give praise to the Lord, proclaim **his name**;
> make known among the **nations** [Gentiles] what he has done,
> and proclaim that his name is exalted.

After Jesus' ascension, the disciples proclaim salvation in Jesus' name to the Gentiles.

Comment: Good point. I added. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This metaphor of salvation being likened to water was common and picked up in the NT:

- Zech 14:8 - On that day **living water** will flow out from Jerusalem, half of it east to the Dead Sea and half of it west to the Mediterranean Sea, in summer and in winter.
- John 4:10 - Jesus answered, “If you knew the gift of God and who is asking you for a drink, you would have asked Him, and He would have given you **living water**.”
- Jer 2:13 - "My people have committed two sins: They have forsaken me, the spring of **living water**, and have dug their own cisterns, broken cisterns that cannot hold water.
- Jer 17:13 - LORD, you are the hope of Israel; all who forsake you will be put to shame. Those who turn away from you will be written in the dust because they have forsaken the LORD, **the spring of living water**.
- John 7:38 - Whoever believes in me, as Scripture has said, rivers of **living water** will flow from within them."
- Isa 12:13 - With joy you will draw water from the wells of salvation.

Note that this is another metaphor similar in function to others such as "The Shepherd", "The First and Last", "The Bridegroom", "I AM", "The Lord of Lords" and "The Rock", etc, that is given to the LORD Jehovah in the OT and applied to Christ in the NT.

- 1 Cor 10:4 - and drank the same spiritual drink; for they drank from the spiritual rock that accompanied them, and that rock was Christ.